# Sum of independent random variables is a martingale which converges almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $ \{X_n\}_{n \ge 1} $ be a sequence of independent random variables satisfying
    $$
    \mathbb{P}(X_n = -n^2) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X_n = \frac{n^2}{n^2 - 1}) = \frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
    The question is to show that $S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n$ is a martingale such that $S_n / n \rightarrow 1$ a.s. and $S_n \rightarrow \infty$ a.s.

**My attempt**: 
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_m] = -m^2 \cdot \frac{1}{m^2} + (\frac{m^2}{m^2 - 1}) \cdot (1 - \frac{1}{m^2}) = -1 + 1=0,
$$
and $\mathbb{E}[S_n] = \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i] = 0.$ For $\mathcal{F}_{n} = \sigma(X_1, ..., X_n)$, we see that

$$
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}[S_{n} | \mathcal{F}_{n - 1}] &=  \mathbb{E}[S_{n - 1} + X_n |\mathcal{F}_{n - 1}] \\
    &= \mathbb{E}[S_{n - 1} |\mathcal{F}_{n - 1}] + \mathbb{E}[X_n] \\
    &= S_{n - 1} + 0 \\
    &= S_{n - 1}.
\end{align*} 
$$
    Moreover,  $\mathbb{E}|S_n| < +\infty$ since
$$
\mathbb{E}|S_n| \le \mathbb{E}( \sum_{i = 1}^n |X_i|) = \sum_{i = 1}^n\mathbb{E}|X_i| = 2n.
$$
    If we let $A_n$ be the event that $X_n = \frac{n^2}{n^2 - 1}$, then $\sum_{n \ge 1} \mathbb{P}(A_n) = \sum_{n \ge 1} (1 - \frac{1}{n^2}) = +\infty $ and since $X_n$ independent for $n = 1, 2, ...$ we have by Borel-Cantelli lemma that  $\mathbb{P}(A_n \text{ i.o}) = 1$. And since $\lim_n X_n = 1$, we can conclude that $S_n \rightarrow \infty$ almost surely.

Is this reasoning correct? If it is, how do I apply the same reasoning using Borel-Cantelli for $S_n/n \rightarrow 1$ a.s. ?

Comment: Your last paragraph "If we let $A_n$ be the event..." is unusual.   Proving $A_n$ occurs infinitely often does not seem useful.  However your unsupported claim "and since $\lim_n X_n=1$" is exactly what you need to prove.  It means you really want to prove $A_n$ occurs all but finitely often.  Borel-Cantelli lemma is useful but not in the way you have done.

Comment: Note also that it suffices to prove $S_n/n\rightarrow 1$ with prob 1, since $S_n/n\rightarrow 1$  implies $S_n\rightarrow \infty$. You will find that independence is irrelevant for this (it is only used to prove the martingale part).

Comment: @Michael Thank you so much! If we suppose instead that $A_n = \{w : X_n(w) = - n^2\}$ then $\mathbb{P}(\liminf{A_n}^c) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(A_n \text{ i.o}) = 1$. So, for $\omega \in \liminf{A_n}^c$ there exists an index $N = N(\omega) \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $X_n(\omega) = \frac{n^2}{n^2 - 1} = 1$ whenever $n \ge N$. Is this sufficent as an argument that $\lim X_n = 1$? And by the way, could you please clearify when or where I was (or supposed) to be using the independency argument for the martingale part?

Comment: Note that $\frac{n^2}{n^2-1} \neq 1$.  Nevertheless if for some $\omega$ we have that $X_n(\omega) = \frac{n^2}{n^2-1}$ for all sufficiently large $n$, then indeed for that $\omega$ we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n(\omega) = 1$.  And you used independence (only) for $E[X_n|F_{n-1}] = E[X_n]$.